# install tensorflow1.1 ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use python version 3.5 64bit on window10，and used cuda8.0.
I was able to successfully use the tensorflow with version r0.8.
I install tensorflow1.1 succeed ,but when i use tensorflow have a problem.

（My system have msvcp140.dll.）
Did anyone encounter this problem when installing a new version?

```
Python 3.5.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 15 2017, 10:43:23) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 35, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 30, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 35, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 30, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Based on the error message, I suspect this is a problem with your `%PATH%` environment variable, which might be missing the directories containing CUDA or (more commonly, since it often gets installed in a different place) cuDNN. I wrote a script to diagnose common issues, so you can try running to see if it has useful suggestions: https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c

Comment: I am very sad that this is still a problem。Here is the output of the information：
ERROR: Failed to import the TensorFlow module.

- Python version is 3.5.

- TensorFlow is installed at: E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow

- All required DLLs are present. Please open an issue on the
  TensorFlow GitHub page: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues

Comment: I just updated the gist with another DLL to check: https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c (it's possible that `NVCUDA.dll` can't be found). Can you try re-running the script? Otherwise, please open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: I think the problem is on the tensorflow version 1.1.0,and now i can use the version 1.0.BUT I don't know how to solve the problem.